# Public domain high resolution vector data

Tags: gis, shapefile, wgs84

Can someone point to me where I can grab high res vector data ?

Preferably WGS84 vector data in Shape file format (Coastlines, nation boundaries, lakes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [GADM2](http://www.gadm.org/) already?

Comment: I am using gadm2 but I am experiencing some problems when doing a country by country union. Using PostGIS. Some countries, ex Canada, seems to have some problematic geometries.